# Navigation bar not displaying menu button for slide out menu

Tags: objective-c

I have one issue ok. I have a slideoutnavigation in my app ok.

When the user logs in they are brought to the home page where the slideoutnavigation is there. The user should be able to swipe to the right to open the menu or click a UIBarButton to also open the menu. Now the swipegesture works but the UIBarButton is giving the option to go back to the login View controller.

Here is the code for when the user clicks log in

```
ParenHomePage *lvc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"parentHome"];
           SlideNavigationController *navcontroller = [[SlideNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lvc];
            ParentMenu *leftMenuParent = (ParentMenu*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ParentMenu"];

            //[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].leftMenu = leftMenuParent;
            navcontroller.leftMenu = leftMenuParent;

            [self presentViewController:navcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any help would be great guys thanks